# JavaScript app permission check

Tags: javascript, security, permissions

I am currently building a JavaScript which contains some areas that are only accessible to a specific usergroup - let's say they bought a product and can enter the product view within the app. (Everything happens on the same page).

Right now my approach would be the following:

// Some request happened and the next component is about to get loaded
...

```
$.get("/api/permission/something", function(result){ // <-- Check whether the user has or has not the permission to access that component
    if(result === "permission granted"){ // <-- this would be the check whether its ok or not to access that component - but this value can be changed manually if someone really wants to (debugger via inspector etc)
        // permission ok
    }
});
```

So basically this would be a vulnerable approach as far as I know. My current solution to keep it as "secure" as possible is to check every following request if the user has permission to be in there or not - to eventually kick him out at some point.

Is there any other way that can be applied in here ?

Comment: What happens in the `permission ok` block? Is it some content from the server or something on the client side (like showing an html element)?

Comment: what do you mean by pattern here? do you want to have a gneralized code so that you dont have to write `result === "permission granted"` in ever response callback?

Comment: @georg I am loading a new component in the users view - so he has access to another level off the app basically. There he can do more stuff.

Comment: @AmmarHasan I may have used bad wording there. I don't need an automated pattern. I am just looking for the most secure solution for this issue

Comment: Can you control the api itself, means that can you return a custom http code from api when there is no permisison?

Comment: Then why not you return HTTP 403 Forbidden Access code when user is not granted permission by "/api/permission/something"? this would prevent your code from executing if user is not having the right permissions.

Comment: I have never done that - could you provide me an example, like how would i handle it on the client and server ? :) I am using node js as backend.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming your are talking about Single Page App when you say "Everything happens on the same page". That means you get your content trough a app endpoint that is loaded with XHR.

Here you have two options:
- your api calls should return proper STATUS codes about trying to receive data
- each object that is returned by your api should have also the permissions that  your user is allowed to. for example

```
"permisssions":{
"view":true,
"delete":false
}
```

Comment: I see where you are comming from, but isn't it possible to manipulate these permission objects with debugger or so ?